# Refresh Google Map without page reload

Tags: jsp, google-maps, refresh

I would like to create a Google map plotter that gets GPS values from a database and puts the position on a Google map using a marker. I already have a basic map which shows a marker on a specified location. This works well, and fetches the initial position which gets displayed on the map.

I loop through the database and fetch the latest entry. I also refresh the map this way:

```
function keepAlive()
{
    <%
        gps = new Gps();

        coordinates = gps.getCoordinates();

//                        out.print(
//                            String.format(
//                                    "alert(%s, %s);",
//                                    new Object[]
//                                    {
//                                        gps.getLatitude(coordinates),
//                                        gps.getLongitude(coordinates)
//                                    }));

        out.print(
            String.format(
                    "var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(%s, %s);",
                    new Object[]
                    {
                        gps.getLatitude(coordinates),
                        gps.getLongitude(coordinates)
                    }));
    %>

    map.setCenter(newLatLng);
    marker.push(newLatLng);
}

setInterval(keepAlive, 10000);
```

Gps is a Java class that does the heavy lifting, and returns the latest record in the database

The refreshing works, owing to the fact that if I uncomment the alert, it keeps popping up dialogs after every 10 seconds. Problem is that no new data gets fetched and it keeps popping the old. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The idea is not to have the variabled being set in the JavaScript dynamically, but having the data fetched by other JSP pages, calling the JSP pages and using JQuery to load the values

This is the function now:

```
function refreshMap()
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'lat.jsp',
                        success: function(data) {
                            newLat = data;
                        }
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'long.jsp',
                        success: function(data) {
                            newLong = data;
                        }
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'oldlat.jsp',
                        success: function(data) {
                            oldLat = data;
                        }
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'oldlong.jsp',
                        success: function(data) {
                            oldLong = data;
                        }
                    });


                    var lineCoordinates = [
                        new google.maps.LatLng(oldLat, oldLong),
                        new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLong),
                    ];

                    lineSymbol = null;

                    // Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
                    lineSymbol = {
                        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                        scale: 4,
                        strokeColor: '#0000FF',
                        fillColor: '#0000FF',
                        fillOpacity: 1,
                    };

                    // Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
                    line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: lineCoordinates,
                        icons: [{
                                icon: lineSymbol,
                                offset: '100%'
                            }],
                        strokeOpacity: 0,
                        map: map
                    });

                    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLong));
                }
```

lat.jsp/long.jsp returns the new GPS coordinates from the databases. Looping through the function with `setInterval(refreshMap, 5000);` makes the map dynamically refreshes the map without the entire page refreshing